# Using XPATH to select child xml nodes in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xpath, xml-namespaces

Im trying to build a validator withing my excel spread sheet.
The program grabs data from an odata service and parses the xml.

My issue is `Debug.Print doc.SelectNodes("d:userId").Item(0).XML` seems to return nothing.

my xml looks like this:

```
<entry>
<content type="application/xml">
            <m:properties>
                <d:userId>user.id</d:userId>
                <d:lastName>name</d:lastName>
                <d:username>user.name</d:username>
                <d:custom01 m:null="true"></d:custom01>
                <d:division>N/A</d:division>
                <d:email>user.name@email.com</d:email>
                <d:department>N/A</d:department>
                <d:empId m:null="true">user.id</d:empId>
                <d:hireDate m:null="true"></d:hireDate>
                <d:jobCode m:null="true"></d:jobCode>
                <d:firstName>user</d:firstName>
                <d:mi m:null="true">N/A</d:mi>
            </m:properties>
</content>
</entry>
```

here is the VBA code:

```
Function getSimpleProperty(propertyName As String, parentNode As IXMLDOMNode) As String

    Debug.Print parentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//content")
    getSimpleProperty = parentNode.SelectSingleNode("/entry/content/m:properties/" + propertyName)

End Function
```

I recieve an error that says "Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'd'"
Ive seen other examples that use `XmlDocument` object however im stuck using `MSXML2.DOMDocument60`

The examples ive seen use a namespace manager but to create one i need to use a method from the `XmlDocument` that isnt available in the `MSXML2.DOMDocument60`.

`Dim nsmgr as XmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable) //doc.NameTable is used in XmlDocument but not DOMDocument60`

How can i create a namespacemanager with only the `MSXML2.DOMDocument60`
 object as my program is already heavily integrated with this and I dont want to have to rewrite the whole thing.

*Edit*

So i made some progress.

i added this before loading the xml:

```
 xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    xmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:d='http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices' xmlns:m='http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata'"
```

This works for:

`Set findRecord = doc.SelectSingleNode("//d:userId[text()='" + userId + "']").parentNode.parentNode.parentNode`

This doesnt work when i try

```
Debug.Print parentNode.SelectSingleNode("content/m:properties/")
```

Comment: what is `.Item(0).XML` supposed to be? Also userId is not a direct child of the documentElement. Try with `doc.SelectNodes("//d:userId").xml` instead. Also: your namespaces need to be defined in the XML else you get a parseError. Example: `<entry xmlns:m='http://tempuri.com' xmlns:d='http://tempuri.com'>`

Comment: I tried ("//d:userId") with no luck, I do have these namespaces declared, I had sensitive data in that xml so i only copied a snippet from it

Comment: You need to post some code, else all is mere guesswork.

Comment: I added the vba code

Comment: What does `Debug.Print parentNode.nodeName` reveal? BTW: using `parentNode` as a variable name is really bad practice.